# Typescript wrapping the object and proxying only some of the it's methods

Tags: typescript

When I use the `Test` class inside another class `Wrapper` I want to be able to proxy the methods to the `test` instance in a generic way `this.test[method]()`.

In this case, I only want to proxy `fly` `swim` and `drive` (same signature for all three).
However the problem is in other methods of the `Test` class, and that is where the TypeScript is complaining.

In first `// 1. addEventListener` if I try to use `keysof` then TypeScript complains because of the method signatures.

In second `// 2. addEventListener` I have tried to create a new type `CustomMethods` via `Pick` utility type, but then I get the error `CustomMethod cannot be used as an index type`

Is there a way to compile this code in `--strict` mode?

```
class Test {
  fly(location: string, listener: Function) {}
  swim(location: string, listener: Function) {}
  drive(location: string, listener: Function) {}

  stopFlying(birds:number[]){}
  stopDriving(racers:boolean[]){}

}

// pick some of the methods from the Test type
type CustomMethods = Pick<Test, "fly" | "swim"| "drive">;


class Wrapper {
  public name: string;
  public test: Test;
  constructor(t:Test) {
    this.name = "event";
    this.test = t
  }

  // 1.
  addListener(method: keyof Test, listener: Function) {
    this.test[method](this.name, listener);
  }

  // 2.
  addListener(method: CustomMethods, listener: Function) {
    this.test[method](this.name, listener);
  }
}
```

[typescript playground demo](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `keyof Pick<Test, "fly" | "swim"| "drive">`, not just `Pick<Test, "fly" | "swim"| "drive">`.

Comment: Basically this is the same answer as @romain-deneau above, but it's better because it is more generic. I could easily use [Omit utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) in the same way If the `api` is really big and I need the majority of the methods from the type.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost good. Indeed, it's even simpler: just indicate the method names in a union types: `method: "fly" | "swim"| "drive"`. If this type is used elsewhere, just give it an alias: `type TestMethodName = "fly" | "swim"| "drive"`.

The TypeScript may be improved this way, to be more idiomatic IMO:

- Favor parameter properties to have terser code for classes
- Skip the `public` keyword since it's implicit but in constructor for parameter properties.
- Prefer `readonly` fields when possible to favor immutability

```
type TestMethodName = "fly" | "swim"| "drive";

class Wrapper {
  readonly name = "event";

  constructor(readonly test: Test) {}

  addListener(method: TestMethodName, listener: Function) {
    this.test[method](this.name, listener);
  }
}
```

Comment: This one works in a way that it satisfies the compiler. But I loose all type inference. That is the reason that I was trying to make it work with the [Pick utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk)

Comment: @ivan-v I don't know where type inference would be lost? The compiler prevents us to pass arguments of wrong types, e.g. `this.test[method](0, 'not-a-listener')`.

Comment: If you use 

`type CustomMethods = Pick<Test, "fly" | "swim"| "drive">;`

`CustomMethods` type will know about `fly` method signature.
Try hovering over `CustomMethods` and your solution in `vs-code`

Comment: `CustomMethods` is a type of a function and implies this usage: `method(this.name, listener)`. This is the reason for your compile error. This usage is not practical from the client side where we need to pass a function! Moreover, `this.test` is no more needed. There's a design flow here: the class `Wrapper` is not a wrapper anymore. Having just the method name preserves encapsulation better and still there's type safety: if the name doesn't match a real `Test` method, it won't compile. IMO it's a better design: simple, safe, efficient.